# How to cancel a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uikit

I'm modally presenting a `UIViewController` with a `UIWebView` as its view. How do I dismiss the `UIWebView` when the user hits a cancel button on it?

One idea I have is to have the cancel button link to http://cancel and then check in

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

If `webView.request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"cancel"`, then dismiss the view controller.

Does the host have to have a dot in it, e.g., "cancel.com"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right path, but you're approach is slightly off. You don't need or want this to be an HTTP URL. Make your URL `cancel:`.

```
<a href="cancel:">Thing to click</a>
```

Then implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in your web view delegate. Something like this (untested):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of using `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` instead just after posting but didn't get to edit the question. Using the scheme of the URL is better. Sweet!

Answer (score 6):

It's not entirely clear if you want to stop loading in a web view or just dismiss the modal view controller that's containing it.

To stop loading:

```
[webView stopLoading];
```

To dismiss the view controller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Don't forget to set the web view's `delegate` to nil before you release it.

Comment: +1 because this is the better way to do it even if all that is wanted is to dismiss the view controller. I have ran into issues with the app crashing if the webView is still trying to load in the background after the view controller is dismissed.